# JSON File clears every time new information is written to it

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

So basically I have a JSON file that is saving every message from my discord server, which it works for the first message, but when a second one is saved to the 'data.txt' file, the original message is deleted/overrided and disappears from the file. How can I make it so that all the messages are saved as separate items...

```
  @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        contents = message.content
        data = [contents]
        for word in contents:
            with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
                data.append(json.dump(str(data), outfile))

            await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: You'll have to load the json into memory as a dict, modify that dict, then write it back to the file.  Json doesn't look like the best format for this purpose.  You want something that you can open in append mode and add more data.  Maybe just a text file that you write `repr(message.content)` to?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I dont want to manually add the data, the bot is supposed to automatically do that for me... Thats why I have the data.append() function... Can you please explain what you mean by adding more data? In my head I think you mean me manually opening  the file and handwriting the data, but thats ultimately what the bot is for. Thanks!

Comment: When I say "you" write to the file I mean you write code that makes the bot do it.  Sorry if that was unclear.  The reason I suggest opening a file in append mode is because file I/O and the `json` module are blocking operations as opposed to asynchronous operations. If your code blocks for too long it can crash your bot.  You can open a file in append mode with `open("file.txt", 'a')`.  This would allow you to write new messages to the file as a kind of log instead of reading the whole file into an object and then writing that object back to the file.

Comment: When I change my code to ("file.txt", 'a'), My list is still just a bunch of empty list items followed by the word "none"... I will print my list here: "[None, None, None, None, None]""[None, None, None, None, None, None]""[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]"

Comment: Why does list.append do this???? I tried list extend also but that broke up every list item into individual characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do.  This will put each message the bot sees on it's own line as a string literal.  Whatever consumer you have should call `ast.literal_eval` on this file line-by-line to reconstitute the messages.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return 
    with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
        print(repr(message.content), file=f)
    await bot/process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, initially I did not understand how to apply your recommendation of repr but now I can see how it is used and it makes more sense, I thought you were saying to rid of the json file and use repr in its place, much appreciated